# Many of the same item in a list

Tags: python, list

Making a simple chance-based game based on CS:GO cases. Say I'd like to have 100 items in a list - 65 blue, 18 purple, 10 pink, 5 red and 2 gold - how could I put these items into a list without typing 100 individual items in?

Comment: hi! welcome to stack overflow! make sure to give us something more to work with next time, like a piece of code and other things you've researched to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary where the values are the counts of the items. Then you only need one item per name:

```
items = { blue: 65, purple: 18, pink: 10, red: 5, gold: 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can 'multipy' a list, that'll repeat all the items. In your case, you could use something like this.

```
l = ["blue"] * 65

## now l = ["blue", "blue", ..]
```

Also adding lists handy as well, so you can do this.

```
l = ["blue"] * 65 + ["purple"] * 18 + ["pink"] * 10 

## now l = ["blue", "blue", .., "purple", ..., "pink", ..., "pink"]
```

Comment: This only works for immutable objects, you will get * n references to the same object for mutable objects.